# Add email to Case record via Email to Salesforce from Outlook

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

according to statement here, from Salesforce online help & training ->

*"If you use a company-provided or third-party email account, you can use Email to Salesforce to assign emails to leads, contacts, opportunities, **and other records** in Salesforce."*

Now I would like to add email from Outlook to Case record instead of Contact/Lead/Opportunity. How can I do that?

I BCC the email address generated by Salesforce but it didn't work.

How can I add the email to Case?

Comment: Are you using Salesforce for outlook desktop or outlook web app?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have "Email to Case" setup and working in SalesForce.  Then you can either email into the SF email address defined by Email to Case or you can install the SF/Outlook plugin and use the Create Case button to create the case in SF.